# How can I use the derived class variable? Base class variable is being used automatically

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am inheriting class Plant and Animal from class Kingdom and class Mammalia from class Animal.

I created Boolean variables fly, milk and fruits in all the classes which are assigned differently according to classes.

There are methods in Kingdom which checks fly, milk and fruits and gives output accordingly. The methods are inherited by all the classes.

But when I am using the object of Plant and mammalia to use the inherited methods the kingdom class variable is used instead of intended class variable.

The code is a bit lengthy. So apologies.

```
class Kingdom
{
    private bool milk, wings, fruits;

    public Kingdom() : this(true, true, true) {}
    public Kingdom(bool m, bool w, bool f)
    {
        milk = m;
        wings = w;
        fruits = f;
    }

    public virtual string me()
    {
        return "Kingdom Member";
    }

    public virtual void Fly()
    {
        if(this.wings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me() + " may Fly.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me() + " can not Fly.");
        }
    }

    public virtual void Fruit()
    {
        if(this.fruits)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me() + " may bear Fruits.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me() + " can not bear Fruits.");
        }
    }

    public virtual void Milk()
    {
        if(this.milk)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me() + " may produce milk.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me() + " can not produce milk.");
        }
    }
}

class Plant : Kingdom
{
    private bool milk, wings, fruits;

    public Plant()
    {
        milk = false;
        wings = false;
        fruits = true;
    }

    public override string me()
    {
        return "Plants";
    }
}

class Animelia : Kingdom
{
    private bool milk, wings, fruits;

    public Animelia()
    {
        milk = true;
        wings = true;
        fruits = false;
    }

    public override string me()
    {
        return "Animals";
    }
}

class Mamalia : Animelia
{
    private bool milk, wings, fruits;

    public Mamalia()
    {
        milk = true;
        wings = false;
        fruits = false;
    }

    public override string me()
    {
        return "Mamals";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!\nLets learn Basic Kingdoms.\n");

        Kingdom p1 = new Plant();
        Kingdom m1 = new Mamalia();

        p1.Fly();
        p1.Milk();
        p1.Fruit();
        Console.WriteLine();
        m1.Fly();
        m1.Milk();
        m1.Fruit();
    }
}
```

These are the warnings I am worried about:

Program.cs(80,35): warning CS0414: The field 'Animelia.fruits' is assigned but its value is never used [E:\VS Code Programms\C#\Assignment\Q5\Q5.csproj]

Program.cs(80,28): warning CS0414: The field 'Animelia.wings' is assigned but its value is never used [E:\VS Code Programms\C#\Assignment\Q5\Q5.csproj]

Program.cs(97,28): warning CS0414: The field 'Mamalia.wings' is assigned but its value is never used [E:\VS Code Programms\C#\Assignment\Q5\Q5.csproj]

Program.cs(63,28): warning CS0414: The field 'Plant.wings' is assigned but its value is never used [E:\VS Code Programms\C#\Assignment\Q5\Q5.csproj]

Program.cs(97,35): warning CS0414: The field 'Mamalia.fruits' is assigned but its value is never used [E:\VS Code Programms\C#\Assignment\Q5\Q5.csproj]

Program.cs(63,22): warning CS0414: The field 'Plant.milk' is assigned but its value is never used [E:\VS Code Programms\C#\Assignment\Q5\Q5.csproj]

Program.cs(63,35): warning CS0414: The field 'Plant.fruits' is assigned but its value is never used [E:\VS Code Programms\C#\Assignment\Q5\Q5.csproj]

Program.cs(80,22): warning CS0414: The field 'Animelia.milk' is assigned but its value is never used [E:\VS Code Programms\C#\Assignment\Q5\Q5.csproj]

Program.cs(97,22): warning CS0414: The field 'Mamalia.milk' is assigned but its value is never used [E:\VS Code Programms\C#\Assignment\Q5\Q5.csproj]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the `milk`, `wings`, `fruits` fields from each subclass. They are already *inherited*. You are declaring them again, which hides the ones in the `Kingdom` class.

Basically, this means that fields you are setting here...

```
public Plant()
{
    milk = false;
    wings = false;
    fruits = true;
}
```

are not the same ones as the ones in `Kingdom`. Therefore the methods in `Kingdom` do not know about these new fields you created.

After you removed the field declarations, `milk`, `wings` and `fruits` will refer to the fields declared in the `Kingdom` class.

Your code should look like this:

```
class Plant : Kingdom
{

    public Plant()
    {
        milk = false;
        wings = false;
        fruits = true;
    }

    public override string me()
    {
        return "Plants";
    }
}

class Animelia : Kingdom
{
    public Animelia()
    {
        milk = true;
        wings = true;
        fruits = false;
    }

    public override string me()
    {
        return "Animals";
    }
}

class Mamalia : Animelia
{
    public Mamalia()
    {
        milk = true;
        wings = false;
        fruits = false;
    }

    public override string me()
    {
        return "Mamals";
    }
}
```

Also, I think the relationships between your classes are a bit weird. `Animal` and `Plant` are *examples* of kingdoms, so they should be instances of `Kingdom`, instead of inheriting from it. And `Mammalia` is not a `Kingdom` at all. The kingdoms are Archaebacteria, Eubacteria, Protista, Fungi, Plantae, and Animalia.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the `milk`, `wings` and `fruit` variables in your derived classes because they already exist in the base class.

To set those variables from the derived classes you already have a constructor which is able to do that here:

```
public Kingdom(bool m, bool w, bool f)
{
    milk = m;
    wings = w;
    fruits = f;
}
```

All you need to do is use that constructor from your base class using the `base` keyword.  For example:

```
class Plant : Kingdom
{    
    public Plant() : base(false, false, true)
    {
    }

    public override string me()
    {
        return "Plants";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Fly(), Milk(), and Fruit() methods are running in the context of the base Kingdom class, and they are accessing the local private class variables in that class.

The problem is that the Kingdom class does not have direct access to the re-defined versions of the variables in the subclasses, hence why you are getting errors that they are not being used.

As others have said, ideally you would not actually re-define the variables in each child class, but instead make the variables in Kingdom "protected" rather than "private". You would then be able to directly set these variables in the constructor of each subclass. However, to address your question of *why* you are getting warnings that the variables in each subclass are not being used, please read on ...

One way to solve this is to add some virtual Get accessor methods in the Kingdom class that can then be overridden in the subclasses in order to read the local re-defined versions of the variables.

Please note: I have used the lamda "expression-bodied methods" syntax here as it makes the GetWings(), GetMilk(), and GetFruit() methods nice and compact. You could expand these out as full-bodied methods if you prefer.

```
class Kingdom
{
    private bool milk, wings, fruits;

    public Kingdom() : this(true, true, true) { }
    public Kingdom(bool m, bool w, bool f)
    {
        milk = m;
        wings = w;
        fruits = f;
    }

    public virtual string me()
    {
        return "Kingdom Member";
    }

    protected virtual bool GetMilk() => milk;
    protected virtual bool GetWings() => wings;
    protected virtual bool GetFruits() => fruits;

    public virtual void Fly()
    {
        if (GetWings())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me() + " may Fly.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me() + " can not Fly.");
        }
    }

    public virtual void Fruit()
    {
        if (GetFruits())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me() + " may bear Fruits.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me() + " can not bear Fruits.");
        }
    }

    public virtual void Milk()
    {
        if (GetMilk())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me() + " may produce milk.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me() + " can not produce milk.");
        }
    }
}

class Plant : Kingdom
{
    private bool milk, wings, fruits;

    public Plant()
    {
        milk = false;
        wings = false;
        fruits = true;
    }

    public override string me()
    {
        return "Plants";
    }

    protected override bool GetMilk() => milk;
    protected override bool GetWings() => wings;
    protected override bool GetFruits() => fruits;
}

class Animelia : Kingdom
{
    private bool milk, wings, fruits;

    public Animelia()
    {
        milk = true;
        wings = true;
        fruits = false;
    }

    public override string me()
    {
        return "Animals";
    }

    protected override bool GetMilk() => milk;
    protected override bool GetWings() => wings;
    protected override bool GetFruits() => fruits;
}

class Mamalia : Animelia
{
    private bool milk, wings, fruits;

    public Mamalia()
    {
        milk = true;
        wings = false;
        fruits = false;
    }

    public override string me()
    {
        return "Mamals";
    }

    protected override bool GetMilk() => milk;
    protected override bool GetWings() => wings;
    protected override bool GetFruits() => fruits;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!\nLets learn Basic Kingdoms.\n");

        Kingdom p1 = new Plant();
        Kingdom m1 = new Mamalia();

        p1.Fly();
        p1.Milk();
        p1.Fruit();
        Console.WriteLine();
        m1.Fly();
        m1.Milk();
        m1.Fruit();
    }
}
```

I got the following result with the above modified code:

```
Hello World!
Lets learn Basic Kingdoms.

Plants can not Fly.
Plants can not produce milk.
Plants may bear Fruits.

Mamals can not Fly.
Mamals may produce milk.
Mamals can not bear Fruits.
```